# How can I see the payload POSTed to a Flask app endpoint that is hosted on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, json, api, google-app-engine, flask

I have an Flask API with a `/do_a_thing` endpoint. When hosted locally I can send a JSON payload using the UI or Postman and the endpoint receives and works as expected. When deployed to App Engine and sending to PubSub and then to the `/do_a_thing` endpoint, it hits a key_error while parsing the payload.

How can I verify the payload structure/data type in Google App Engine. There doesn't seem to be a console or log that records/shows the payload. I'm wondering if it is being transformed on the way.

I'm using flask so parsing is done like so:

```
payload_as_dictionary = request.json
value_i_want = payload_as_dictionary['key']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endpoint is creating an error right now and therefore, presumably, is not sending back a response. Without access to the console to see what is happening, you would need to do something like this:

```py
from flask import jsonify

try:
    payload_as_dictionary = request.json
    value_i_want = payload_as_dictionary['key']
except Exception as e:
    return jsonify({
        'error': str(e),
        'payload': payload_as_dictionary 
    })
```

Wrap everything in the try except block so that every error gets caught. While normally that wouldn't be ideal, it may be a good temporary solution to see what's happening.

Now when you send the post request, you'll get the payload echoed back to you with a string representation of the error that was thrown (if any) during the request.

Comment: Thank you, this was useful for troubleshooting. The encoding-decoding process was not quite correct and at one point I was receiving bytes instead of a string.